# Separate dictionary and text

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp

I have many sentences like as follows (This is one sentence and not many sentences) :

```
'Hello , I , am, fine.' ,{'type': 'bold', 'text': 'Multi class f1 score'}, {'type': 'mention', 'text': '@Abhishek'}, ' Singh you can continue with the deep learning specialization from Andrew Ng. It is very much informative and lots to learn and its very smplified and for the certificate you can apply for financial aid option..the courses will be available in 15 days'
```

I want to separate the text and dictionary as separate parts like:

```
1. Hello , I , am, fine.
2. {'type': 'bold', 'text': 'Multi class f1 score'}
3. {'type': 'mention', 'text': '@Abhishek'}
4. Singh you can continue with the deep learning specialization from Andrew Ng. It is very much informative and lots to learn and its very smplified and for the certificate you can apply for financial aid option..the courses will be available in 15 days
```

Splitting by `","` wont help as it will lead to two problems:

1. Dictionary keys and value pair won't be separated and look like `{'type': 'mention' 'text': '@Abhishek'}` .
2. I will loose all the `,` from the part 1

Note that the text might contain emoji's also in utf-8 encoded form.

How can this be done?

Comment: What have you tried or attempted?

Comment: I was trying to do analysis on telegram chats whose data was stored in json format.like - {"id":9860,  "type":"message",  "date":"2020-06-11T01:01:25", 
 "from":"A.",  "from_id":1072244642,    "text":["mohak pl check it out ",{"type":"link","text":"https:\/\/www.kaggle.com\/abilashivs\/kernel3e217ae073"}]}  . I have a column name text containing values as per this dictionary and now want to extract out the text from it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using regex. First extract the dictionary parts from the string and then extract the ones in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to split your content in the way you want:

```
import re

string = "'Hello , I , am, fine.' ,{'type': 'bold', 'text': 'Multi class f1 score'}, {'type': 'mention', 'text': '@Abhishek'}, ' Singh you can continue with the deep learning specialization from Andrew Ng. It is very much informative and lots to learn and its very smplified and for the certificate you can apply for financial aid option..the courses will be available in 15 days'"
results = re.findall(r"'(.*?)'|({.*?})", string)
results = [item for elem in results for item in elem if len(item)] # Clean empty records
for e in results:
    print(e)
```

This will return:

```
Hello , I , am, fine.
{'type': 'bold', 'text': 'Multi class f1 score'}
{'type': 'mention', 'text': '@Abhishek'}
 Singh you can continue with the deep learning specialization from Andrew Ng. It is very much informative and lots to learn and its very smplified and for the certificate you can apply for financial aid option..the courses will be available in 15 days
```

Comment: But when I tried , i didnt got desired result.. Please try with text =  "'Hey ', {'type': 'mention_name', 'text': 'Krish', 'user_id': 935251183}, ' \nI had a doubt.\nIf we have an unbalanced dataset. Target variable has Yes/No values.\nYes-9500\nNo-500\nWe have 10 features.\nNow there are 4 features that have around 3000 null values.\n\nSince we’ll have to balance the dataset eventually, should we drop the 3000 records ?\nOr should we drop the columns and then balance the dataset.'"

Comment: Got the solution by removing escape sequences